# Where should implement the methods of AsyncTask class if have multiple classes in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have four classes:

1. `MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity`
2. `MainAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List>`
3. `Intermediate` extends MainAsyncTask and have two functions. (FuncA, FuncB)
4. `Leaf extends Intermediate` and implementation of `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`.

When I run the application it prompts:

> Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{}: android.os.NetworkonMainThreadException.

How can I get rid off the Error. As far as My understanding is concerned, `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`should be implemented in `MainAsyncTask` class?

Classes are : 
MianActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Leaf object = new Leaf();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               object.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainAsyncTask.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class MainAsync  extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {


    }
}
```

Intermediate.java

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Intermediate extends MainAsync{

    public Document FunA(){
        System.out.println("Printed FunA()");
        String url = "http://blogs.tribune.com.pk/story/37034/zakir-naik-has-a-large-following-in-pakistan-should-we-be-alarmed/";
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public void FunB(){ System.out.println("Printed FunB()");}
}
    }
```

Leaf.java

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Leaf extends Intermediate{

       Document HTM = FunA();

        public void FunC() {
            String heading = "";
            System.out.println("Printed FunC()");
            Elements seep = HTM.select("h1");
            for (Element foo : seep) {
                heading = foo.text();
                System.out.println(heading);
                break;
            }

        }

        public void FunD() {
            System.out.println("Printed FunD()");
        }

        public void FunE() {
            System.out.println("Printed FunE()");

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            FunB();FunC();FunD();FunE();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {


        }
    }
```

The purpose of doing in this way is to add `FuncA` and `FuncB` along with `AsyncTask` methods in one class that is `Leaf` class.

Comment: The error is saying you are attempting to run network operations on the main thread. You have not posted code so it is not possible to determine where your error lies.

Comment: It is impossible that your posted code throws this exception because there are no network operations.

Comment: @Kuffs It is throwing. Kindly run the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: @Kuffs It did not helped me. Code is updated. Now see the code.

Comment: It would help you if you learned how to use an AsyncTask properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a stack trace I would say:

Initiating your `Leaf` class causes the `HTM` variable to be initiated.

The `HTM` variable is initiated by calling the `FunA` method.

The `FunA` method runs network accessing code and is not running inside `DoInBackground` (and therefore running on the main thread).

Your network code can only be run inside `DoInBackground` if you wish to not get a `NetworkOnMainThread` Exception.

The exception is thrown before you even start the `AsyncTask` as just the act of creating it causes the `FunA` code to run.

Move this line inside `DoInBackground` so it runs when the `AsyncTask` is executed and not when it is created.

```
Document HTM = FunA();
```

On a separate note, your class hierarchy is very convoluted. You do not need Intermediate or Leaf classes. All that code could be easily moved to the `MainAsync` class and so would be much easier to understand.